# Android - error: package android.support.test does not exist

Tags: android, unit-testing

I try to run unit test, but I get error

> error: package android.support.test does not exist

In my grade file I have

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

But I still get error

Gradle

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply from: 'versionCode.gradle'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionName "1.0." + VERSION_CODE
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(VERSION_CODE)
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [...]
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/UserStories']
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'jniLibs', include: ['*.jar', '.so'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'co.lujun:androidtagview:1.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.0.1'
    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
    implementation 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:2.0.6'

    compile group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxjava', version: '2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'

    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8"
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
}


tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'generateReleaseBuildConfig') {
        task.dependsOn 'increaseVersionCode'
    }
}
```

Comment: check the module gradle file in which you want to run the test. Specify where are u adding the above dependency to! i mean in which gradle file

Comment: use only `testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'`

Comment: show your `build.gradle`.

Comment: done, please take a look

Comment: Would you try adding this: `allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: on which level should I add this ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your gradle file is like this:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    ...
}
```

Does it work now?

Comment: You used `testCompile` right? That's deprecated. Try changing to `testImplementation `

Comment: Can you post your entire gradle file please?

Answer (score 2):

In the gradle file for example two, replacing androidTestImplementation with implementation it seems to fix the issue. Check and update me once.

Comment: This was the one that made it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use like bellow:

`dependencies.gradle`:

```
ext {
    versions = [
            // For project configuration
            java                  : JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8,
            compileSdk            : 28,
            targetSdk             : 28,
            minSdk                : 21,
            buildTools            : '28.0.2',
            dokka                 : '0.9.16',

            // For app
            kotlin                : '1.2.61',
            coroutine             : '0.24.0',

            appCompat             : '1.0.0-beta01',
            recyclerview          : '1.0.0-beta01',
            constraintLayout      : '2.0.0-alpha1',
            cardview              : '1.0.0-beta01',
            browser               : '1.0.0-beta01',
            androidKtx            : '1.0.0-beta01',

            dagger                : '2.16',
            firebaseCloudMessage  : '17.1.0',
            firebaseAnalytics     : '16.0.3',
            playServices          : '15.0.1',
            exoPlayer             : '2.8.2',
            flexbox               : '1.0.0',
            material              : '1.0.0-beta01',

            room                  : '2.0.0-beta01',
            lifecycle             : '2.0.0-beta01',

            rxKotlin              : '2.2.0',
            rxAndroid             : '2.0.2',

            moshi                 : '1.6.0',
            okhttp                : '3.11.0',

            timber                : '4.7.1',
            threeTenABP           : '1.1.0',
            rxBinding             : '2.1.1',

            fresco                : '1.10.0',

            kotshi                : '1.0.4',

            frescoImageViewer     : '0.5.1',
            markwon               : '1.1.0',
            aVLoadingIndicatorView: '2.1.3',
            glide                 : '4.8.0-SNAPSHOT',

            // For wearable
            wear                  : '2.3.0',
            playServicesWearable  : '15.0.1',
            supportWearable       : '27.1.1',

            // For testing
            junit                 : '4.12',
            truth                 : '0.42',
            espresso              : '3.1.0-alpha4',
            mockito               : '2.21.0'
    ]
    libraries = [
            .....
            .....
            // For testing
            junit                 : "junit:junit:${versions.junit}",
            espressoCore          : "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:${versions.espresso}",
            espressoIntents       : "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:${versions.espresso}",
            roomTest              : "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:${versions.room}",
            truth                 : "com.google.truth:truth:${versions.truth}"
    ]
}
```

And `build.gradle(project...`:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: rootProject.file('dependencies.gradle')

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-rc02'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    apply from: rootProject.file('dependencies.gradle')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And `build.gradle(Module...`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ww.ww.ww"

        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 13
        versionName "2.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
....
    }
....
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //espresso
    testImplementation libraries.junit
    testImplementation libraries.truth
    androidTestImplementation libraries.espressoCore
    androidTestImplementation libraries.espressoIntents
...

}
```

Notice to this line:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android features such as Context, you need to put your test file is in the `androidTest` directory and annotate the class with `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your project has been migrated to AndroidX then you should update the import statements in your instrumented tests to reference the correct packages, e.g. like this instead:

import **androidx.test.platform.app**.InstrumentationRegistry;

import **androidx.test.ext.junit.runners**.AndroidJUnit4;